# C# Validating Multiple TextBoxes

Tags: c#, textbox, registrykey

I have several TextBoxes on a page. Values for the textboxes are pulled from registry keys that are created. I have an update button that the user can press to update the values in the registry. I need to add functionality so that if they change a value in one or multiple textboxes an errorprovider would show up next to the textbox they changed. I know I can write code for each and every textbox, but that would be messy and long. Is there a way that I could use a foreach loop?

```
private void tabPage1_Enter(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        //            Root: HKLM64; Subkey: "Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon";ValueType: string; ValueName: "AutoAdminLogon"; ValueData: "1";Check: IsWin64
        //          Root: HKLM64; Subkey: "Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon";ValueType: string; ValueName: "DefaultUserName"; ValueData: "mydealerlot";Check: IsWin64
        //        Root: HKLM64; Subkey: "Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon";ValueType: string; ValueName: "DefaultPassword"; ValueData: "sdc1234";Check: IsWin64
        //      Root: HKLM64; Subkey: "SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System";ValueType: dword; ValueName: "EnableLUA"; ValueData: "0";Check: IsWin64

        AutoAdminLogin = (string)Registry.GetValue(@"HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\MDL\SystemRestart", "AutoAdminLogon", null);
        DefaultUserName = (string)Registry.GetValue(@"HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\MDL\SystemRestart", "DefaultUserName", null);
        DefaultDomain = (string)Registry.GetValue(@"HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\MDL\SystemRestart", "DefaultDomain", null);
        DefaultPassword = (string)Registry.GetValue(@"HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\MDL\SystemRestart", "DefaultPassword", null);
        SymbolicName = (string)Registry.GetValue(@"HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\MDL\RemoteAgent", "SymbolicName", null);
        ServerAPIKey = (string)Registry.GetValue(@"HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\MDL\RemoteAgent", "ServerAPIKey", null);


        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(AutoAdminLogin))
        {
            AutoAdminLogin = (string)Registry.GetValue(@"HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon", "AutoAdminLogon", null);
        }

        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(DefaultUserName))
        {
            DefaultUserName = (string)Registry.GetValue(@"HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon", "DefaultUserName", null);
        }

        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(DefaultDomain))
        {
            DefaultDomain = (string)Registry.GetValue(@"HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon", "DefaultDomain", null);
        }
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(DefaultPassword))
        {
            DefaultPassword = (string)Registry.GetValue(@"HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon", "DefaultPassword", null);
        }
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(SymbolicName))
        {
            SymbolicName = (string)Registry.GetValue(@"HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\MDL\RemoteAgent", "SymbolicName", null);
        }
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(ServerAPIKey))
        {
            ServerAPIKey = (string)Registry.GetValue(@"HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\MDL\RemoteAgent", "ServerAPIKey", null);
        }

        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(DefaultUserName))
        {
            DefaultUserName = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("USERNAME");
        }

        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(DefaultDomain))
        {
            DefaultDomain = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("USERDOMAIN");
        }

        if (AutoAdminLogin == null || AutoAdminLogin != "1")
            AutoAdminLogin = "0";

        tbUserName.Text = DefaultUserName;
        tbDomain.Text = DefaultDomain;
        tbPassword.Text = DefaultPassword;
        tbSymbolicName.Text = SymbolicName;
        tbServerAPIKey.Text = ServerAPIKey;

        cbAutoLogin.Checked = (AutoAdminLogin == "1") ? true : false;

        compareLoginUsername();

        compareLoginPassword();
}
```

Thank you for your time,

-S

Comment: Write a wrapper class over the .NET TextBox Control. Define some property or member in which you store default value from any of your environment variables, set that property in the constructor.. so on.. what say?

Comment: What do you want to have happen, and when?  Is this supposed to happen on Validate?  Or all at once when the button is clicked?  How will you know the value has changed...compare to the variables?

Comment: as the user would type it would check to see if textbox.text is equal to the registry key. if not then the errorprovider would pop up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can wire up all boxes to same logic

```
box1.TextChanged += TextchangedHandler();
box2.TextChanged += TextchangedHandler();
box3.TextChanged += TextchangedHandler();
```

And the handler can handle what to do with the text box, its data, etc